# PI Approximation not approximating right

Tags: c++, pi

i just started on C++ and i tried to convert my working PI approximation JS code to C++
But when compiling my C++ it doesn't approximate correctly...

I think it's because i'm not using double variables at the right way.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double four = 4, pi = 4, num = 1;
bool lever = false;

int calcpi() {
        while (true) {
            num = num +2;
            if (lever) {
                lever = false;
                pi = (four/num) - pi;
            } else if(lever == false){
                lever = true;
                pi = (four/num) + pi;
            }
            cout << pi <<"\n";
        }   
}
    
int main(){
    calcpi();
}
```

Comment: *working PI approximation JS code to C++* -- Throw away the JavaScript code and write the C++ version as if JavaScript doesn't exist.   That means you should *learn* C++, and not use JS as a model in writing your code.  Doing line-by-line translations from JavaScript (or any other language) to C++ will more times than not, lead to buggy code or unexpected results.

Comment: Case in point: `int calcpi()` -- where do you actually return an `int` in that function?  You don't, thus the program has undefined behavior.

Comment: side note: `else if(lever == false)` should be simply `else`: same result, easier to read

Comment: I recommend watching videos by Matt Parker about computing Pi by hand. He does one every year on Pi day. Great other formulas for computing Pi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're implementing the approximation

```
π = 4 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + 4/9 – …
```

In that case, the line `pi = (four/num) - pi;` is backwards. It should be `pi = pi - (four/num);`, which represents the subtraction terms.

Also, subtraction from the initial value of 4 should be the first operation, so the `lever` flag should be initialized to `true`.

Here's the modified version that I got working after a little bit of troubleshooting.

```
void calcpi() {
    double pi = 4.0, num = 1.0;
    bool lever = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        num = num + 2.0;
        if (lever) {
            lever = false;
            pi = pi - (4.0 / num);
        }
        else {
            lever = true;
            pi = pi + (4.0 / num);
        }
        std::cout << pi << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This does give a slowly converging approximation of Pi.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// changed values of constant and variable
// to comply with the mathematical formula:
// pi = 4 * (0 + 1/1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ...)

// four = 4 was changed to one = 1, because
// we use it as our numerator, which is always 1

// pi = 4 was changed to pi = 0 (first element
// of our infinite series)

// num = 1 was changed to num = -1 (at the
// beginning of the while loop, before we
// manipulate pi, we add 2 to num, so
// -1 + 2 = 1 <- first value of our denominator
double one = 1, pi = 0, num = -1;
bool lever = false;

void calcpi() {  // void instead of int, because this function doesn't return anything
    while (true) {
        num += 2;  // I prefer x += y instead of x = x + y, doesn't really matter
        if (lever) {
            lever = false;
            pi -= (one / num);  // negative elements of the infinite series
        } else if(lever == false){  // this is redundant: we know lever == false at this point
            lever = true;
            pi += (one / num);  // positive elements of the infinite series
        }
        cout << 4 * pi << '\n';  // our variable 'pi' is actually pi/4
    }
}

int main() {
    calcpi();
}
```

I assumed you use the [Leibniz formula for π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) and I tried not to modify your code too much, but be wary - it's quite wonky.

If I were to write something similar, it'd look something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void calcpi(int iter) {
    double pi = 0, denom = 1;
    bool lever = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
        if (lever) {
            lever = false;
            pi -= (1 / denom);
        } else {
            lever = true;
            pi += (1 / denom);
        }
        denom += 2;
        std::cout << 4 * pi << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    calcpi(426200); // should be enough given the default cout precision
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you explained what have you changed and why.

Comment: Sure thing, gimme a sec and I'll add comments to my answer.

Comment: This is actually a great answer

Comment: [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard)'s answer made me realise my assumption about using the Leibniz formula for pi was wrong; nevertheless, I'm leaving my solutions up.